# python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7

I get a IndexError: list index out of range Error. I have get the recipient lists for each message. I have collapsed the lists of recipients into a single list. How do I fix that problem?

```
import json
import pymongo # pip install pymongo
from bson import json_util # Comes with pymongo
import re
from pymongo import MongoClient
# The basis of our query
FROM = "kenneth.lay@enron.com"


client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:user123@ds033499.mongolab.com:33499/enron')
db = client.enron
mbox = db.mbox

# Get the recipient lists for each message

recipients_per_message = db.mbox.aggregate([
    {"$match" : {"From" : re.compile(r".*{0}.*".format(FROM), re.IGNORECASE)}}, 
    {"$project" : {"From" : 1, "To" : 1} }, 
    {"$group" : {"_id" : "$From", "recipients" : {"$addToSet" : "$To" } } }                    
    ])['result'][0]['recipients']

# Collapse the lists of recipients into a single list

all_recipients = [recipient
                  for message in recipients_per_message
                  for recipient in message]

# Calculate the number of recipients per sent message and sort

recipients_per_message_totals = \
    sorted([len(recipients) 
    for recipients in recipients_per_message])

# Demonstrate how to use $unwind followed by $group to collapse
# the recipient lists into a single list (with no duplicates
# per the $addToSet operator)

unique_recipients = db.mbox.aggregate([
    {"$match" : {"From" : re.compile(r".*{0}.*".format(FROM), re.IGNORECASE)}}, 
    {"$project" : {"From" : 1, "To" : 1} }, 
    {"$unwind" : "$To"}, 
    {"$group" : {"_id" : "From", "recipients" : {"$addToSet" : "$To"}} }
    ]['result'][0]['recipients'])

print all_recipients
print "Num total recipients on all messages:", len(all_recipients)
print "Num recipients for each message:", recipients_per_message_totals
print "Num unique recipients", len(unique_recipients)
```

this is the traceback

```
  IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-85-b1e01d6382fb> in <module>()
   18   {"$project" : {"From" : 1, "To" : 1} },
   19   {"$group" : {"_id" : "$From", "recipients" : {"$addToSet" : "$To" } } }
   --->20 ])['result'][0]['recipients']
   21 
   22 # Collapse the lists of recipients into a single list

   IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback of your error; it tells us on what line the exception occurred and what called that line, etc.

Comment: `'result'` is probably an empty list. What is the result of `db.mbox.aggregate(...)` excluding `['result'][0]['recipients']`?

Comment: Nope. Wrong diagnostic. Your aggregate is not returning any results. That is where the error is coming from. So please show a sample of your documents in your question. And that means some of the documents that are going to match.

Comment: Even better. Declare your aggregation pipeline as a var outside of the call and dump that with `pp` as well. Then we (and you) can see how your re is resolving in the dict.

Comment: So what happened? Was it that the way you were trying to implement a regex was not working?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, changing this:

```
{"$match" : {"From" : {"$regex": "^" + FROM, "$options": "i"} }},
```

Is this your card?

If so then it looks like you were trying to interpolate an actual regex into what MongoDB really wants as a string. Hence the form.

P.S **Drop** the case-insensitive match. It's useless since your whole collection is being scanned as a result. Rather keep all email adresses in lowercase in your collection. Case is not valid for email anyhow. Lowercase your storage and your input. Everything will work faster.